# Как убрать "белый экран" при старте своего созданного приложения

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Добрый день! Я написал некое приложение. При его запуске, перед показом экрана mainActivity, появляется, примерно, на 1 секунду белый экран. Если я правильно понимаю то этот "белый экран" - это Devise Screen. Ка сделать чтобы его небыло или заменить его на фоновый рисунок?

Comment: Вы какой-то дополнительный фреймворк использовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите тёмную тему и,при необходимости, нужный вам бэкраунд в теме вашего приложения, либо в стиле для вашей активности:

*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<application
        ....
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

*res/values/styles.xml*

```
<resources>    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/window_background</item>
    </style>
    …
```

*res/values/colors.xml*

```
<resources>
    <color name="window_background">#00ff00</color>
    …
```

Скорее всего, вы говорите про момент анимации, которая выполняется при открытии приложения из лаунчера. На момент её начала, приложение ещё не запустилось, у лаунчера нет информации, как оно выглядит, поэтому вид берётся из стилей.

Затем уберите всю долгую инициализацию из главной активности. Первый экран должен отрисоваться как можно быстрее. Если у вас там 1 секунда и вам она мешает - значит там точно что-то есть.
Фоновую картинку ставить не нужно, она только создаст ощущение тормознутости приложения.